# Text in a JTextField not wrapping around

Tags: java, swing

My original plan today was to learn how to use the `JProgressBar`, but now I am stuck with a new problem which I was not expecting. So here is how my `JFrame` looks like right now.

[image: The Frame]

The problem is that the `JTextField` right under the `JTextArea` is not wrapping around. It is going beyond the size of the `JFrame`. I want it to resize relative to the `JFrame`. How can i do that? I have tried the `JLabel` but it does the same thing, only it adds ellipses in the end where the text overflows.

Comment: It's not going beyon the size of the JFrame. It's just that the text it contains is too long to fit inside the text field. Would you like the JFrame to resize itself each time the text grows inside the text field? What should it do once you have 4000 characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a `JTextArea` if you intend for the field to expand vertically to accommodate the text.

`JTextField`s are intended for a single line of text.